Serializing a large number of small data sets in python
I am writing mass spectrometry data reduction software and I have some questions about data storage types.
My program may be working with tens of thousands of raw data files whose data are stored in a custom class. The data set I'm working with now has about 20,000 files. With pickle, this results in a load time of about ten seconds, which I'm trying to reduce.
Each of these raw data files is relatively small. Here's an example:

He 18210    MK-1-19A 1.1A 5min H25  2022-05-08T04:48:26 time_sec    2.06    3.06    4.03    5.01    40.07
3.489   4.672910E-11    4.908442E-14    4.632142E-14    -1.482541E-14   7.113753E-14
9.589   4.594885E-11    4.315875E-14    3.164914E-14    -1.218974E-14   7.186164E-14
2.389   2.063851E-10    2.153866E-11    1.090697E-10    1.517824E-15    4.289825E-13
8.489   2.064248E-10    2.156692E-11    1.089338E-10    2.401720E-15    4.487897E-13
14.689  2.062997E-10    2.151732E-11    1.090502E-10    -1.505463E-15   4.616923E-13
20.689  2.060995E-10    2.150736E-11    1.089118E-10    -2.859083E-15   4.777400E-13
26.789  2.060045E-10    2.149887E-11    1.087125E-10    -2.544102E-15   4.873777E-13
32.889  2.061123E-10    2.145929E-11    1.087295E-10    -7.094666E-16   4.952666E-13
38.889  2.060522E-10    2.147935E-11    1.087669E-10    -4.477479E-16   5.052122E-13
44.989  2.059155E-10    2.150907E-11    1.086589E-10    -1.669057E-15   5.228772E-13
51.189  2.061038E-10    2.147520E-11    1.086972E-10    -1.649827E-15   5.401987E-13
57.189  2.057349E-10    2.142206E-11    1.087919E-10    -3.717346E-15   5.526003E-13
63.289  2.050218E-10    2.142769E-11    1.085385E-10    -3.715051E-15   5.623006E-13
69.390  2.054654E-10    2.140363E-11    1.086267E-10    -5.173371E-16   5.603773E-13
He 18210    MK-1-19A 1.1A 5min H25  2022-05-08T05:04:29

These data are stored in a custom class:
class DataEntry:
    def __init__(self, helium_number, analysis_label, timestamp, time_sec, PAB_data, raw_data, data_status):
        self.helium_number   = helium_number # unique analysis identifier
        self.analysis_label  = analysis_label # user-input analysis label
        self.timestamp       = timestamp # date and time analysis was initiated
        self.PAB_data        = PAB_data # pre-analysis baseline data                  
        self.raw_data        = raw_data # raw mass spec intensity data
        self.time_sec        = time_sec # timestamps associated with raw_data intensity
        self.analysis_type   = self.determine_analysis_type(analysis_label) # analysis type          
        self.active          = True # inactive calculations (e.g. to remove a lineblank) this will be 0
        self.reduced         = False # whether or not the analysis data has been reduced
        self.data_status     = data_status # size of raw data, True = active, False = excluded as outlier

This class includes a mix of ints, strings, bools, datetime, and pandas dataframes.
When I search for the fastest type of storage container, I come across hf5, however, this had an insane overhead--around 60-70kB per analysis--yielding a file that is unreasonably large given the relatively small amount of data it contains. I never let it get past the 4GB mark, but for reference the equivalent pickle file is 104 MB.
I think, but I'm not sure, that my problem was storing too many separate things in the hf5 file: I was breaking the class down into its components, and storing each of those separately.
I can see three ways of going through this:

Importing the raw data files as pandas dataframes, then before parsing, storing those 'raw' dataframes in hf5 or parquet. I suspect this will reduce the hf5 overhead due to reducing each file/analysis down to one object to be stored instead of nine. I worry that this might end up increasing the loading time due to needing to parse every file every time the program loads, though the parsing function is admittedly pretty light.
I parse everything once and store the objects in some kind of data storage container I'm not aware of that has speed but less overhead than hf5. I need to break the class down into its components, store them, and re-build the class from the loaded data whenever the program runs.
I store the pandas dataframes in one container, and the strings/bools/etc in a separate json/csv/something. I worry that the data could become misaligned, though, and besides, this is only going to be as fast as the slowest of the two approaches at best.

I realize that none of you can come to my apartment and run the code for me to see what's going to be fastest--I'm more just tired of spinning my wheels on this topic and looking for pointers from someone who knows more than I do.
How and in what would you store this data, Python gurus?
Below is the full script:
import os 
import pickle
import platform
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import customtkinter as ctk
from tkinter import ttk, scrolledtext
from raw_data.dataenty import DataEntry
from raw_data.identify_sequences import identify_sequences


def load_data():
    if os.path.exists('data/raw_data.pkl'):
        with open('data/raw_data.pkl', 'rb') as f:
            return pickle.load(f)
    else:
        return []
    

def save_data(data):
    if not os.path.exists('data'):
        os.makedirs('data')
    with open('data/raw_data.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(data, f)
    

# loop over raw data files and extract data
def get_raw_data():
    root=ctk.CTk()
    ctk.set_appearance_mode('light')
    root.title('HeMan Pro - Importing Raw Data')

    # progress bar
    progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient='horizontal', length=300, mode='determinate')
    progress_bar.pack(pady=10)

    # log text area
    log_text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, wrap=ctk.WORD, height=20, width=60)
    log_text.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

    # load existing data and list of processed files
    all_data = load_data()
    loaded_files = [f'He {analysis.helium_number}.txt' for analysis in all_data]

    # determine the location of the data folder
    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        data_folder = 'C:\\alphachron data\\raw' # standard location on Achron Windows PC
    else: 
        data_folder = 'raw' # use a local raw data folder for development on Linux/MacOS

    # setup process bar
    files_to_process = [f for f in os.listdir(data_folder) if f.startswith('He') and f.endswith('.txt')]
    progress_bar['maximum'] = len(files_to_process)
    
    # insert some text in the logging area so the user knows something is happening
    log_text.insert(1.0, 'Importing raw data files...')
    
    # loop over the files in the data folder
    for filename in files_to_process:
        if filename not in loaded_files: # check only for new files
            file_path = os.path.join(data_folder, filename)
            try:
                # get the raw data and append it to the list of all data
                helium_number, analysis_label, timestamp, time_sec, PAB_data, raw_data, data_status = parse_raw(file_path)
                analysis = DataEntry(helium_number, analysis_label, timestamp, time_sec, PAB_data, raw_data, data_status)
                all_data.append(analysis)

            # file is empty
            except ValueError:
                log_text.insert(1.0, f'Skipping {filename}: Empty data file.\n')

            # file is not in the expected format, probably another empty file
            except Exception as e:
                log_text.insert(1.0, f'Error processing {filename}: {e}')

            # update the progress bar
            progress_bar.step(1)
            root.update()

    # sort the data by helium number
    all_data = sorted(all_data, key=lambda entry: entry.helium_number)
    
    # break up the raw data into sequences
    all_data, sequence_data = identify_sequences(all_data)

    # signal GUI to close after processing
    root.destroy()

    # save the data
    save_data(all_data)

    return all_data, sequence_data


def parse_raw(file_path):
    # import the data file as df
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep='\t', header=1, usecols=range(6))    

    # check if the data file is empty
    if df.shape[0] <= 3:
        raise ValueError(f"File contains no data.")
    
    # grab unique analysis data from non-header 'headers'
    helium_number  = int(df.columns[0].split()[1])
    analysis_label = str(df.columns[1])
    timestamp      = pd.to_datetime(df.columns[2], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

    # grab the pre-analysis baseline and raw analysis data
    PAB_data = df.iloc[0:2].dropna(axis=1).apply(pd.to_numeric)
    raw_data = df.iloc[2:-1].dropna(axis=1).apply(pd.to_numeric)
    
    # these data files are a mess, jesus, just rename the headers manually
    data_cols        = ['time_sec', '2 amu', '3 amu', '4 amu', '5 amu', '40 amu']
    raw_data.columns = data_cols
    PAB_data.columns = data_cols

    raw_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    # get timestamps from time_sec
    time_sec = raw_data['time_sec']

    # re-organize raw_data
    org_raw_data = {
        "2 amu":     raw_data['2 amu'],
        "3 amu":     raw_data['3 amu'],
        "4 amu":     raw_data['4 amu'],
        "5 amu":     raw_data['5 amu'],
        "40 amu":    raw_data['40 amu'],
        "4/3 Ratio": pd.DataFrame(index=raw_data.index, columns=['4/3 Ratio'])
    }

    # calculate 4/3 Ratio * 1000
    org_raw_data['4/3 Ratio'] = raw_data['4 amu'] / raw_data['3 amu'] * 1000

    # filter negative data as inactive
    data_status = {}
    for mass in org_raw_data:
        data_status[mass] = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(org_raw_data[mass].shape[0], dtype=int), columns=[mass])
        if mass not in ['4/3 ratio', '5 amu']:
            data_status[mass] = (org_raw_data[mass] > 0).astype(int)

    # set any 4/3 ratio data to negative if the corresponding 3 amu or 4 amu data are negative
    data_status['4/3 Ratio'] = data_status["4/3 Ratio"].mask(
        (data_status['3 amu'] == 0) | (data_status['4 amu'] == 0), 0
    )

    return helium_number, analysis_label, timestamp, time_sec, PAB_data, org_raw_data, data_status


Write all the 20,000 files in one file and  just work with that one file. Do you have 20,000 files for each dataset/machine? What's the scale? If it would take a few seconds, what's the problem? You don't have to deliver real-time software for this application? Total size would be less than 50MB for each 20,000 file? Also you can use compression.

Wouldn't compression just make things slower? Storage size isn't a problem, I'm more concerned about read time in the case that the user has 40-60,000 files or more. Real-time, no, but having your program take thirty or more seconds to open feels wrong. So what format would you choose for that one file?

Do you need to load new data each time?  Can it be stored in a DB?

Yes, checking for and loading new data every time is critical. Loading old data in a readable format is also critical as otherwise the user has to wade through tens of thousands of files named "He 12345.txt" to identify an older dataset by timestamps. I don't see why it couldn't be stored in a DB but I have no experience with any of them.

Mass spec machines take hours to run an experiment. Right? If a user has too many files and it would take a minute or two to process things that should be fine. It is not like every minute, a user wants to process 20K files. If you are using local PC for their storage, CSV, JSON, etc. are fine. Of course you can use binary format (e.g., using Avro, Parquet, HDF5) if you want. My point is you can combine all files. Also, don't try to add unnecessary packages, each they have overhead and require maintenance. Compression does not make things slow.

This is still an open question, but the solution that I've settled on is to use google's protocol buffers to store the data. I use a file dataentry.proto:
syntax = "proto3";

message DataEntry {
  int32 helium_number = 1;
  string analysis_label = 2;
  string timestamp = 3;  
  repeated double time_sec = 4;

  message PABData {
    repeated double time_sec = 1;
    repeated double amu2 = 2;
    repeated double amu3 = 3;
    repeated double amu4 = 4;
    repeated double baseline = 5;
    repeated double amu40 = 6;
  }
  PABData pab_data = 5;

  message RawData {
    repeated double amu2 = 1;
    repeated double amu3 = 2;
    repeated double amu4 = 3;
    repeated double baseline = 4;
    repeated double amu40 = 5;
    repeated double ratio43 = 6;
  }
  RawData raw_data = 6;

  message DataStatus {
    repeated int32 amu2 = 1;
    repeated int32 amu3 = 2;
    repeated int32 amu4 = 3;
    repeated int32 baseline = 4;
    repeated int32 amu40 = 5;
    repeated int32 ratio43 = 6;
  }
  DataStatus data_status = 7;
}

message DataList {
  repeated DataEntry analysis = 1;
}

I then use protoc.exe to convert that into a Python class that can be utilized by protobuf in import_raw
            try:
                helium_number, analysis_label, timestamp, time_sec, PAB_data, raw_data, data_status = parse_raw(file_path)
                
                # analysis data
                analysis_pb = all_data_pb.analysis.add()
                analysis_pb.helium_number = helium_number
                analysis_pb.analysis_label = analysis_label
                analysis_pb.timestamp = timestamp.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
                analysis_pb.time_sec.extend(time_sec.tolist())
                
                # pre-analysis baseline data
                PAB_data_pb = analysis_pb.pab_data
                PAB_data_pb.time_sec.extend(PAB_data['time_sec'].tolist())
                PAB_data_pb.amu2.extend(PAB_data['2 amu'].tolist())
                PAB_data_pb.amu3.extend(PAB_data['3 amu'].tolist())
                PAB_data_pb.amu4.extend(PAB_data['4 amu'].tolist())
                PAB_data_pb.baseline.extend(PAB_data['baseline'].tolist())
                PAB_data_pb.amu40.extend(PAB_data['40 amu'].tolist())
                
                # raw analysis data
                raw_data_pb = analysis_pb.raw_data
                raw_data_pb.amu2.extend(raw_data['2 amu'].tolist())
                raw_data_pb.amu3.extend(raw_data['3 amu'].tolist())
                raw_data_pb.amu4.extend(raw_data['4 amu'].tolist())
                raw_data_pb.baseline.extend(raw_data['baseline'].tolist())
                raw_data_pb.amu40.extend(raw_data['40 amu'].tolist())
                raw_data_pb.ratio43.extend(raw_data['4/3 Ratio'].tolist())
                
                # data status
                data_status_pb = analysis_pb.data_status
                data_status_pb.amu2.extend(data_status['2 amu'].to_numpy().flatten())
                data_status_pb.amu3.extend(data_status['3 amu'].to_numpy().flatten())
                data_status_pb.amu4.extend(data_status['4 amu'].to_numpy().flatten())
                data_status_pb.baseline.extend(data_status['baseline'].to_numpy().flatten())
                data_status_pb.amu40.extend(data_status['40 amu'].to_numpy().flatten())
                data_status_pb.ratio43.extend(data_status['4/3 Ratio'].to_numpy().flatten())

This reduces the load time by approximately 6x from ~12s to 2s.
